# Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). OpenSSL internal error: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE how to solve?

Tags: openssl, cryptography, wkhtmltopdf, odoo-10, fips

Wkhtmltopdf failed (error code: -6). Message: ../crypto/fips/fips.c:151: OpenSSL internal error: FATAL FIPS SELFTEST FAILURE

Earlier I had wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1.4 which was working fine after updating to UbuntuPro it started giving out above error.
So I had upgraded to 0.12.6 then also it started giving out error.
So I then degraded to 0.12.5. (with patched qt) the same error

What am I doing wrong here? Please help.

Server is having OS ubuntu 18.04 with Ubuntu Pro ESM and after this is enabled it started giving out error.

Applicaiton is Odoo10 / OS is as above.

I tried to search answer to this, but i didn't got any solution related to Odoo10 + FIPS + this.

Comment: When do you get the error?  Running your app?  Building it?

Comment: I was getting error while running an Odoo on production server, But now the problem is somehow resolved. Steps I have taken is as (1) i had unlink wkhtmltopdf and wkhtmltoimage from /usr/bin directory (2) then i did rm command for file (3) i installed 1 upgraded version [trial and error] (3) then it get installed and started working fine {version installed was wkhtmltox-0.12.5.1} thank you all